# Python/Tornado error on app launch

Tags: python, tornado

I am repeatedly getting this error with my Tornado app on launch:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado/database.py", line 59, in __init__
    args = dict(conv=CONVERSIONS, use_unicode=True, charset="utf8",
NameError: global name 'CONVERSIONS' is not defined
```

I have installed Tornado and MySQLdb with pip. I have uninstalled and re-installed both. I am running against a remote MySQL instance.

I am baffled and not sure how to troubleshoot. Any advice?

Comment: Try `import MySQLdb.converters` and see if there is an `ImportError`.

Comment: Yes! Seeing an import error for libmysqlclient.18.dylib. I have seen this when setting up this project on another machine and can hopefully debug. Thank you!

Comment: Check if mysqldb is in `site-packages`.

Comment: It is. Ultimately I needed to set my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, everything is working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately this was masking this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I was able to resolve this by setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

if you run it within MAC OS and Eclipse, you should add DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH into eclipse' environment setting.